# function Iterating over a dictionary with If conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question for the below code,  which is basically a function taking 2 parameters one is a column and one is a dataframe, and I'm having a hard time to understand the for loop iterating over the column and checking if values in the column is keys in the empty dictionary "langs_counts", how is it possible to check when it's an empty dictionary, please explain to me the for loop and why we put 'entry' between square brackets.

```
for entry in col:
   if entry in langs_count.keys():
            langs_count[entry] += 1
   else:
            langs_count[entry] = 1

    # Define count_entries()
    def count_entries(df, col_name):
    """Return a dictionary with counts of 
    occurrences as value for each key."""

    # Initialize an empty dictionary: langs_count
        langs_count = {}

        # Extract column from DataFrame: col
        col = df[col_name]

        # Iterate over lang column in DataFrame
        for entry in col:
            # If the language is in langs_count, add 1
            if entry in langs_count.keys():
                langs_count[entry] += 1
            # Else add the language to langs_count, set the value to 1
            else:
                langs_count[entry] = 1


    # Return the langs_count dictionary
    return langs_count   

    # Call count_entries(): result
    result = count_entries(tweets_df, 'lang')

    # Print the result
    print(result)
```

Comment: When `lang_count` is an empty dictionary, then `entry in lang_count.keys()` is always False. Then the instruction `langs_count[entry] = 1` creates the key with  `entry` content associated with value 1.

Comment: It is actually building the `lang_count` dictionary by counting the occurrence of a certain `key` in the data (`col`). The line `langs_count[entry] = 1` will create an entry in that dictionary with `key` `entry` if that doesn't exist.

Comment: Instead of using a dictionary to count stuff you can use a Counter: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: 'please explain why we put square brackets': the square brackets are similar to indexing from a list  `list[0]`. It returns the value at the key given in square brackets.

Comment: @toti08   thanks for the answer, so [entry] is the key changing every time the loop goes on and if it's true it will increase the value of the current key by 1 otherwise make a new key from the current entry and give it a value of 1 ? , am I correct ?

Comment: @Moberg I will look into that but this is just a practice question in an online course  and I'm trying to understand it , thank you

Comment: @NChauhan I don't understand , we use this langs_count[entry] = 1 to make a new key in the dictionary as entry is values from col ,right ?

Comment: @a.alashqar exactly, so in this way a dictionary counting the occurrence of each key is created.

Answer (score 1):

why we put 'entry' between square brackets?

the thing in the square brackets is called a key.

It is just a simplification for indexing:

example code :

a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': [1, 2]}

a["d"] = 5 in the machine it becomes: a.__setitem__("d",5)

if "d" does not exists as a key, it will create one.If it does,the function assign a new value to it